# Unable to map naked domain (non www) to Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: dns, cloudflare, static-site, namecheap, cloud-storage

Good day, I am trying to host a static site on G Cloud Storage. I followed the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website and all was successful. I purchased a domain from namecheap volunux.com and I named my bucket during creation as [www.volunux.com](http://www.volunux.com) after verifying the ownership in Search Console. I wasn't satisfied with the "Not secure" thingy, so I wanted HTTPS, I should have used Load balancer but I was looking for something cheap at the moment. So I opted for Cloudflare to get me a free SSL and all was fine but here is the problem. My site works at [www.volunux.com](http://www.volunux.com), https://www.volunux.com

but never works when it is: volunux.com, http://volunux.com, https://volunux.com

For close to 24 hours since yesterday, I have been searching for solution to this problem all over the internet.

1. Some suggested and said, one have to create two bucket in GCS to serve both www and non-www.
2. Some, one have to create another bucket and in the web configuration, set the MainPageSuffix as https://www.volunux.com so that redirect will be perform.
3. Some, one have to create a cname record to c.storage.googleapis.com which I did but didn't work.
4. Some, one have to create an A record to set the IP to my hosting provider, I assume GCP but it didn't work either.
5. Some, I have to create a page rule and redirect all request from volunux.com with or without protocol to https://www.volunux.com

I think #1 would have worked but I have to maintained two separate buckets for one thing and #2, I don't know if it is standard practice but from #3 to #5. All efforts prove abortive. I have read through threads on Stackoverflow, CloudFlare community, personal blogs, all didn't work out for me. I have performed a URL Rewrites, 301 redirects from volunux.com/* to https://www.volunux.com/$1 but all efforts prove abortive based on the solutions I have found on the internet, I am confused at this stage because I don't know what to do. I am thinking of moving back to Github Pages using Jekyll or even to AWS S3 but I don't want to do that just yet.

Somebody please help. Attached are the screenshot of configurations.

[image: Cloudflare 1] [image: Cloudflare 2] [image: CloudFlare mode] [image: Namecheap] [image: Google Bucket Domain name]

Comment: Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

1. Set up the Google cloud storage bucket to the naked domain / non-www domain e.g. **example.com**
2. Then use Cloudflare to set up CNAME at the naked domain to c.storage.googleapis.com which has CNAME flattening by default.
3. Then add an A record to the 'www' subdomain to a private address such as '192.0.2.1'
4. Then add a Cloudflare rule in 'Rules' that is a **Forwarding URL** with status code '301 - Permanent Redirect' from **[www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)***   to **https://example.com/$1**

This means only 1 bucket to the naked domain and if anyone tries to go to **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** it will rewrite to **https://example.com**.  So always HTTPS as well, works great.